# replacing all x numbers except last 4 within input value

Tags: php, substring, substr

I have an input that looks like this

```
<input value="{{gameAccount.getAccountNumber() }}" disabled name="accountNumber" type="text">
```

which displays:

```
123456789
```

but I want it to display

```
*****6789
```

I get confused when it is in input value in this particular case with gameAccount.getAccountNumber()

```
substr($something?, 0, -4) . '****';
```

How do I go about this? thanks in advance

I also saw `substr_replace()` function...

Comment: You need it to replace as the user types or on form submission?

Comment: on form submission, its just there displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ficuscr points out this is a better one liner for this:

```
$gameId = '123456789';
$gameId = str_repeat('*', strlen($gameId) - 4) . substr($gameId, -4);
```

There may be a more elegant way to do this but this will work:

```
$gameId = '123456789';

$gameIdLenToMask = strlen($gameId) - 4;
$mask = str_pad('', $gameIdLenToMask, '*');

$gameIdMasked = substr_replace($gameId, $mask, 0, $gameIdLenToMask);

// Prints: "*****6789" 
var_dump($gameIdMasked);
```

For more information see the docs for [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) and [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) on php.net.

Comment: my two cents... `echo str_repeat('*', strlen($gameId))  . substr($gameId, -4);`

Comment: @ficuscr much nicer! Just need to add -4 to the first `strlen` call. I'll add that to my answer. If you make one I can edit it out.

Comment: if input happens to be fewer than 4 characters, `str_repeat` won't be happy with a negative number.

Comment: Feel free to adapt your answer.  Deserve the points for taking time to answering a string function question ;)

Answer (score 1):

One other option, you can use the length minus four as the limit argument for preg_replace.

```
$new = preg_replace('/./', '*', $str, strlen($str) - 4);
```

If you aren't sure that your string will be at least four characters, you can use max to be sure the limit doesn't go negative.

```
$new = preg_replace('/./', '*', $str, max(0, strlen($str) - 4));
```